# Yii:Show Published Post And Approved Comment at RecentComments List

Tags: php, yii

I used `yii blog from Yii Framework`

I want  Show Only Published Post And Approved Comment at RecentComments List

I used This code at Comment Model

```
public function findRecentComments($limit=10)
{
    return $this->with('post')->findAll(array(
        'condition'=>'t.status='.self::STATUS_APPROVED.'status='.Post::STATUS_PUBLISHED,
        'order'=>'t.create_time DESC',
        'limit'=>$limit,
    ));
}
```

But Show All Post And Approved Comment in RecentComments List

I want Show Published Post And Approved Comment at RecentComments List

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting condition for relation model is done within with() function.
I think findAllByAttributes() is more readible so here's solution using this function

```
public function findRecentComments($limit=10)
{
   return $this->with(array('post' => array(
                    'condition' => 'post.status=:status',
                    'params'    => array(':status' => Post::STATUS_PUBLISHED),
            )))->findAllByAttributes( array( 
                self::getTableAlias(false, false).'.status' => self::STATUS_APPROVED
            ), 
            array(
                'order'=> self::getTableAlias(false, false).'.create_time',
                'limit' => $limit
            ) );
}
```